# primefaces update tree with node expansion causing issues

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tree

I have the following tree with 3 types of nodes.

```
<p:tree id="tree" value="#{treeViewBackingBean.root}"   
            var="item" 
            style="width:auto; ">

    <p:ajax event="expand" process="@this" listener="#{treeViewBackingBean.onNodeExpand}" />
    <p:ajax event="collapse" process="@this" listener="#{treeViewBackingBean.onNodeCollapse}" />

    <p:treeNode type="NegotiatingUnit" >
        ...
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="UnionHeader" >
        ...
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="Union" >
        ...
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
<p:commandButton action="#{treeViewBackingBean.save}" update="tree" id="save" value="save" />
```

In the node expand event I set the property expanded to true so that post refresh the node stays expanded.

```
public void onNodeExpand(NodeExpandEvent event) {
    System.out.println("onNodeExpand() " + event + " event " + event.getTreeNode().isExpanded());
    event.getTreeNode().setExpanded(true);
}
```

The problem here is the save button doesn't work when even one of the nodes are expanded?

Is changing treenode object on expand event causing any trouble? how to get this fixed.

I have started working with primefaces 4 in JBoss EAP 6.1 environment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by adding `process="@this"` to the command button using reference from [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14145242/185041). The validation error on the page was causing the button action to abort and `INVOKE APPLICATION LOGIC` phase was not executed.

Comment: `process="@this"` will make the call send only the `p:commandButton` component. Why do you get a validation error?